# gridview row blinking based on some conditions

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have this gridview which in which I want certain rows to blink based on some conditions.
I have tried javascript and jquery but nothing worked.

[javasccript example](http://forums.asp.net/p/1375904/3287108.aspx)

[jquery](http://www.aspmemo.net/2012/03/gridview-rows-blink-using-jquery-in.html)

I tried jquery in above link but it is giving me error

> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

I actually want to use it coz it matches my current requirement.
My current requirement has that, rows which satisfies 3 set of conditions should blink

```
<style type="text/css">
    .bgRow
    {
        background-color: white;
    }
    .norRow
    {
        background-color: Silver;
    }
</style>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="yourUrl/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setBG(GridAlarm)
        {
        var id = "#" + GridAlarm;
        $(id).find("tr").each(function ()//error comes here while debuggigng
        {
            var css = $(this).attr("class");
            if (css != null && css == "bgRow")
                $(this).addClass("norRow").removeClass("bgRow");
            else if (css != null && css == "norRow")
                $(this).addClass("bgRow").removeClass("norRow");

        });
        setTimeout("setBG('" + GridAlarm + "')", 1000); //1000 is equal to one second and call function every one second.
    }
</script>
```

the gridview code in design

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridAlarm" CssClass="bgRow" EmptyDataText="NoData" CellPadding="7" CellSpacing="1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="true" OnRowDataBound="GridAlarm_RowDataBound" OnPageIndexChanging="GridAlarm_PageIndexChanging">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TagName" HeaderText="TagName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Value" HeaderText="Value"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AlarmStatus" HeaderText="Alarm Status"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AlarmRaisedDateTime" HeaderText="Alarm Raised"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AlarmClearedDateTime" HeaderText="Alarm Cleared"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="AlarmAckDateTime" HeaderText="Alarm Acknowledgement"  />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
          <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:CheckBox ID="chk_delete" runat="server" />
          </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and below code behind

```
protected void GridAlarm_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        alarmStat = (e.Row.Cells[3].Text);
        ClearDate = (e.Row.Cells[5].Text);
        AckDate = (e.Row.Cells[6].Text);

        foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            if (alarmStat.Equals(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["A_Clear"].ToString()))
            {
                cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            }
            else if (alarmStat.Equals(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["A_Raise"].ToString()))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(AckDate) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ClearDate)))
                {
                    cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
                }
                else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AckDate) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ClearDate)))
                {
                    e.Row.CssClass = "bgRow";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

i also had to add following in page load

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "BG", "setBG('" + GridAlarm.ClientID + "')", true);
```

But it gives error as mentioned above..

As for the conditions required for the gridview rows to blink you can see in code itself that is it should blink when status is Raised and AckDate and ClearDate are null or empty..
Status,AckDate,ClearDate are present as columns in grid as you can see in code.

What is wrong in above code?
Is there any other way I can solve this problem?

Comment: from the error the 1st point is have you included jquery in your page?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: yeah i posted the code but some how it did not post completely I have edited question again

Comment: y r you using 2 versions of jquery ?

Comment: @KarthikGanesan i think if we add the url in script is that enough? i am sorry but the posts or articles i have referred till now has followed above way only. and yes i am doing it for first time.also i think the url i have used if i run on browser they should show the whole script but they do not exist

Comment: @KarthikGanesan as i said i really have no knowledge about jquery its jus a sudden task given to implement and i came across the example in link mentioned as jquery so i used it..

Comment: yes just the URL should be fine

Comment: @karthinkganesan well the url is not working I suppose and I don't know which other url to use.

Comment: try using this link <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> or you can download latest jquery from their site and include it in your project..

Comment: @karthinkganesan it is working thanks can u post ur comment in answer

Comment: @Silver I have added that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using this link

```
`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`
```

or you can download latest jquery from their site and include it in your project.